# Grasp stability of a robot

Tags: robotic-arm, stability

I have read some researches and sources about "grasp stability", but I don't understand what it is exactly.

If a grasp is stable, does the hand grasp the object perfectly, accurately or strictly?

What is the exact correspondence of stable grasp in robotic world?

Comment: Grasp stability isn't a robotics term, nor it's located within mathematics but is a subjective measurement used in psychological experiments. If a human grasps an object, it's possible to judge, if the grasp make sense or not. First studies about hand movements were made by psychologists before the advent of computers under the term Labanotation. Grasp stability was mentioned in the year 1956 by Napier grasp taxonomy for describing a certain kind of power grasp.[1] From the perspective of robotics the problem is, to transfer this general notation into a machine readable expert system which is

Comment: able to map a real grasp to the notation. [1] Cutkosky, Mark R., and Robert D. Howe. "Human grasp choice and robotic grasp analysis." Dextrous robot hands. Springer, New York, NY, 1990. 5-31.